# Работа с ресурсами java

Tags: java

Есть проект, в котором используется мавен. В проекте надо в метод передать путь к файлу. Именно путь, строку. Не надо получать сам файл, нужно только путь. Если создать папку рядом с папкой src, в которую полужить нужные файлы, то потом когда пишешь "doc/hello.txt" в программе, все работает, но нужно сделать что бы эта папка doc была внутри jar файла, и из проекта, когда он уже запакован нужно получить доступ как то. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вопрос очень интересный, есть предположение, что никак. Так как мы будем получать путь к файлу как нечто "~/home/!....jar.doc/hello.text". Возможно единственным выходом будет только получить этот файл через обычный способ `getResourceAsStream()` и скопировать его куда нибудь.

Comment: Попробуйте такую конструкцию ИмяКласса.class.getClassLoader().getResource("имяФайла"). Тут вопрос в другом... Передать имя файла куда? Это внутренний ресурс и вы сможете иметь доступ только из вашего Java-кода. Из вне к нему не доступишься.

Comment: С чем именно у вас проблема? С запаковкой ресурса в JAR? С открытием ресурсов? С форматом путей к ресурсам?

Comment: С форматом путей к ресурсам